# error running yarn build about big integer literals

Tags: yarnpkg

I'm trying to install crater app and it says to do yarn build.  I keep getting errors, and everything is up to date so I am lost on how to fix this one:

> error during build:
> Error: Transform failed with 3 errors:
> assets/vendor.6c423067.js:56507:1751: error: Big integer literals are not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2019", "firefox78", "safari13.1")
> assets/vendor.6c423067.js:56507:3030: error: Big integer literals are not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2019", "firefox78", "safari13.1")
> assets/vendor.6c423067.js:56507:3070: error: Big integer literals are not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2019", "firefox78", "safari13.1")
> at failureErrorWithLog (/var/www/admin.thehigheryougo/crater/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1493:15)
> at /var/www/admin.thehigheryougo/crater/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1282:29
> at /var/www/admin.thehigheryougo/crater/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:629:9
> at handleIncomingPacket (/var/www/admin.thehigheryougo/crater/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:726:9)
> at Socket.readFromStdout (/var/www/admin.thehigheryougo/crater/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:596:7)
> at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
> at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:290:12)
> at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:265:9)
> at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:204:10)
> at Pipe.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
> error Command failed with exit code 1.

I am familiar with npm and how to fix issues with that, but this is my first time using yarn and I couldnt find a related topic for how to resolve it.  Please help!